# Display dynamic html content like an epub/ebook, without converting html to epub format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a responsive, mobile optimized reading experience similar to an epub/ebook reader, like the Kindle app, or iBooks, using dynamic html as the source.

Imagine a long article or blog post that requires a lot of vertical scrolling to read, especially on a small mobile device. What I would like to do is break the long page into multiple full-screen sections, allowing the user to use left/right navigation arrows and/or the swipe gesture to "page" through the article.

There are many JS libraries available that can create a "slide show" or "carrousel" of pre-defined slides (using divs or other container elements). But I want the text and html content to dynamically re-flow to fit any device viewport and still be readable... just like an epub/ebook user interface, like the Kindle app or iBooks. So, for the same article, there would be many more "pages" on a phone than there would be on a tablet or desktop viewport, and those "pages" would need to be dynamically created/adjusted if/when the viewport size changes (like switching from portrait to landscape on a mobile device).

Here is an example of a javascript .epub reader: [epub.js](http://futurepress.github.io/epub.js/reader/#epubcfi(/6/16[xchapter_002]!/4/2/2/2/2[c002p0000]/1:0))

... notice the responsive behavior. When you resize your viewport, all the text re-flows to fit the available space, increasing or decreasing the total number of "pages". The problem is that epub.js requires an .epub file as its source.

What I want is the same user interface and functionality for an html page.

I have searched and searched for some kind of library that can do this out of the box, but haven't been able to find anything.

I realize that I could use a conversion script to convert my html page into an .epub file, and then use epub.js to render that file within the browser, but that seems very round-about and clunky. It would be so much better to mimic or simulate the .epub reader user experience with html as the direct source, rendering/mimicking a client side responsive ebook user experience.

Does anyone know if something like this already exists, or how I could go about building it myself?

The crucial functionality is the dynamic/responsive text-reflow. When the viewport dimensions are reduced, the text/content needs to reflow to the next "page" to avoid any need for vertical scrolling. I don't know how to do this efficiently. If I were to code it myself, I might use something like the jQuery Columnize plugin, setting all columns to `width: 100vw; height: 100vh`, so that each column is like a "page", and then figuring out how to create a swipe UI between those "pages".

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/internetarchive/bookreader

Comment: This is a really broad question and not specific or technical enough to be posted here. As such, it doesn't deserve an answer and maybe needs to disappear? Anyways you need to be looking for "responsive pagination" scripts/libraries. From 2012, [here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277573/4378314), this is where I'd start. Use JS to analyze 'long-form' HTML content and break it up dynamically according to viewport size. From there figure out controls for animating pages (swiping, arrows, etc). If you also had in mind dynamic server communication, that's another can of worms.

Comment: @user2655393 have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This becomes very difficult if the html page is complex, eg with precisely positioned elements or images. However if (as in the epub.js example) the content consists only of headings and paragraphs, it is achievable.

The basic idea is to progressively add content until just before the page overflows. By keeping track of where we start and stop adding content, clicking to the next page is a case of changing the page start to the previous page end (or vice versa if you're going back).

### Process for reshaping content into pages

Let's assume you have all your content in one long string. Begin by splitting all the content into an array of words and tags. It's not as easy as splitting by whitespace as whitespace between `<` and `>` should be ignored (you want to keep classnames etc within each tag). Also tags should be separated as well, even if there is no whitespace between the tag and a word.

Next you need a function that checks if an element's contents overflow the element. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/determine-if-an-html-elements-content-overflows) has a copy-paste solution.

You need two variables, `pageStart` and `pageEnd`, to keep track of what indexes in the array are the beginning and end of the current page.

Beginning at the index in `pageStart` you add elements from the array as content to the page, checking after each add whether or not the contents overflow. When they do overflow you take the index you're up to, minus 1, as the index for `pageEnd`.

### Keeping tags across page breaks

Now if all's ticketyboo then this should fill the page pretty well. When you want to go to the next page set your new `pageStart` as `pageEnd + 1` and repeat the process. However there are some issues that you may want to fix.

Firstly, what happens if the page overflows in the middle of a paragraph? Strictly speaking the closing tag, `</p>`, is not required in HTML, so we don't need to worry about it. But what about the start of the next page? It will be missing an opening tag and that is a major problem. So we have make sure we check if the page's content begins with a tag, and if it doesn't then we get the closest opening tag prior to the current `pageStart` (just step back along the array from `pageStart`) and add it in before the rest of the content.

Secondly, as shown in the example, if a paragraph continues onto the next page, the last line of the current page is still justified. You need to check if `pageEnd` is in the middle of a paragraph and if so add `syle="text-align-last:justify;"` to the opening tag of that paragraph.

### Example implementation

A pen showing all this in action is at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMJMZZ

The HTML page contains all content in one long element. The content is taken directly from the container `#page` and reformed into pages, depending on the size of `#page`. I have't implemented justifying the last line if a page break occurs within a paragraph. Resize the `#page` element in the css and see how the content resizes itself - note that since the page size is fixed you'll have to use click forward and back to trigger a recalculation. Once you bind the page size to the window size, recalculating pages on the fly simply involves adding a resize event listener to the window that calls `fillPage`.

No doubt there are numerous bugs, indeed it will sometimes display things incorrectly (eg skipping or repeating words at the beginning or end of a page), but this should give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: This seems to be a very good solution too, just needs a bit of care with the style. But the it catches the very last word on the viewable area and "back" and "forward" buttons are pretty right.

Comment: This definitely seems to be the closest to the implementation requested. Thanks for being thorough and providing examples. Although, i wonder what the performance would be like with large array's of text... That being said, I'll give ppl a bit more time to answer before giving out the bounty. Thus far, your the top candidate for it...

Comment: @JaSuperior the array is calculated only once. For very large blocks of content the initial load time may well be noticeable, and you may want to consider dynamic loading with Ajax. Once loaded performance when changing pages should be the same as the algorithm is just stepping through the same array. Performance between page switches is instead dependent on how much content can fit on a page.

Comment: yea... but wouldnt i need to re-initialize if the screen/container size changed? how else would it know how account for the dimension change if, say, the user changed the orientation of their device?

Comment: Well I'm not into performance thing yet...athough this solution is not the more responsive one. The given solution above (http://jsfiddle.net/samu101108/WTPzn/240/ ) is the best for responsiviness and it's a matter of putting the navigation buttons and that will be done...

Comment: @JaSuperior You shouldn't need to re-initialise. The entire content is split into an array of tags and words at the start. Changing the page size by resizing the window or reorienting the device doesn't require the array's contents to be recalculated, it only needs to determine what section of the array to display on the page, which is comparatively cheap. In the pen above `splitInput()` which turns content into an array is only run at `window.onload`.

Comment: Here's a one liner to split the content (using a regex instead of a custom split function) `let splittedContent = htmlString.match(/<[^>]*>|[^<\s]+/gm)`. 
For the rest, I'm still working on optimizing it (for content over 10k words it takes more than a few seconds)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js) repository on GitHub. Otherwise, you can create a one-page website with many sections, each one as high as the viewport, by using only [CSS](https://medium.com/@ckor/make-full-screen-sections-with-1-line-of-css-b82227c75cbd) ([demo](https://codepen.io/ckor/pen/lBnxh)):

```
.section { height: 100vh; }
```

or by using [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript), adding an anchor to each section to navigate between them, and applying a responsive unit (my [demo](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/details/KBBMLM/)) for the text of each section, to [adapt](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/) it on resize... Something like this:

```js
var curr_el_index = 0;
var els_length = $(".container").length;

$(".next_section").on("click", function(e) {
  curr_el_index++;
  if (curr_el_index >= els_length) {
    curr_el_index = 0;
  }
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".container").eq(curr_el_index).offset().top
  }, 300);
  return false;
});

$(".previous_section").on("click", function(e) {
  curr_el_index--;
  if (curr_el_index < 0) {
    curr_el_index = els_length - 1;
  }
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".container").eq(curr_el_index).offset().top
  }, 300);
  return false;
});
```

```css
  * {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
  }
  section {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-size: 6vw;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">Section 1 <a href="#" class="previous_section">Previous</a> <a href="#" class="next_section">Next</a></section>
<section class="container">Section 2 <a href="#" class="previous_section">Previous</a> <a href="#" class="next_section">Next</a></section>
<section class="container">Section 3 <a href="#" class="previous_section">Previous</a> <a href="#" class="next_section">Next</a></section>
<section class="container">Section 4 <a href="#" class="previous_section">Previous</a> <a href="#" class="next_section">Next</a></section>
<section class="container">Section 5 <a href="#" class="previous_section">Previous</a> <a href="#" class="next_section">Next</a></section>
```

**EDIT #1**

An idea of algorithm, that come from a [my codepen](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/details/QyBoQV), that uses the same *jQuery plugin*:

1. Create your reader layout, copying the whole text in it
2. Use [this](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) jQuery plugin to check the text inside the viewport ([demo](http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html))
3. Count the number of characters/WORDS with "*`Onscreen`*" label in the
   viewport (a [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144868/regex-match-count-of-characters-that-are-separated-by-non-matching-characters))
4. Split the whole text in a `list` containing as many characters/WORDS as
   there are in the "*`Onscreen`*" label
5. Create a `section` for each element of the obtained `list`, filling each
   `section` with the relative text; the number of elements of the `list`
   gives you the number of pages (`sections`) of the whole text. You may
   navigate between `sections` like above
6. On `resize` event, redo [2-5] algorithm steps

Cheers

Comment: I like this option, will come in handy

Comment: I think i explained the intent best in my below comment to @ravi

Comment: Also look above at the comments left on the OP

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have a div that will contain the whole text (let's call this div `#epub_container`). Then, you will have a div with the same size of the page viewport (let's call it `#displayer`) and it will contain `#epub_container`.

`#displayer` will have css `overflow:hidden`. So when the site loads, it will only show the first page, because the rest of the `#epub_container` will be hidden.
Then you need a page navigator to increment/decrement the page number. When the page number changes, we will move the top offset of the `#epub_container` based on that.

This is the jQuery function:

```
function move_to_page() {
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = window.innerWidth;

    var $displayer = $('#displayer');
    var offset = $displayer.offset();
    $displayer.height(height - offset.top - 5);

    var $epub = $('#epub_container');
    var offset_top = offset.top - $displayer.height() * m_page;
    $epub.offset({top: offset_top, left: offset.left});
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy4tae68/)

EDIT: call `move_to_page()` after the text reflow in order to recompute the pages.

[image]

Comment: A row of text can be half a row between two pages (like top half at the bottom of page 1 and bottom half on the top of page 2). Is there anyway to handle this issue?

Comment: @SSuen yes. The move_to_page function should get the line-height of the div and make sure not to "cut" a line in half. The offset_top should always be a multiple of that line-height

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin that handles this perfectly. It has features like dark mode, font changing, line height adjustment, select chapter in a side nav menu, save and restore scrolling/reading position. You can find it for free on git hub at https://github.com/E-TechDev/Html-Book-Reader

**Screenshots**
[Light Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmkLy.jpg) [Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spCbS.jpg) [Side Nav Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Nl2.jpg) [Change Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvyKE.jpg) [Adjust Paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2k81.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32931158)

Answer (score -1):

You can try CSS scroll snap points on text with columns

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap_Points

Somehow make the columns as wide as the viewport, and allow horizontal snapped scrolling.

**Update**
I mean to try to do the text flowing entirely using css. Pen:
https://codepen.io/ericc3141/pen/RYZEpr

```
body {
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
}

#columns-test {
    height: 80vh;
    columns: 90vw auto;
}
```

Comment: The question being asked refers to the algorithm required for reflowing and repaging the text if a resize event fires in the client. Your suggesstion works fine for providing the actual animation, but not reflowing the text.

Comment: @JaSuperior Updated with example. No algorithm is needed, because the layout is handled by CSS and the browser.

Comment: Now that I actually try this though, it does seem snap-points is not terribly well supported. I imagine there's probably other solutions floating around...

Answer (score -2):

All you need is to insert a page break at the right places when you load the page.  You can take the cue from here:

[Dynamic Page-Break - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241240/dynamic-page-break-jquery)

Here you can set the page height to your viewport height.  You can handle the rest with javascript and css.

Comment: The question being asked is "how does one programmatically determine where the right places are". Both myself and the person asking the question are seeking an algorithm that can evaluate the text and determine where the breaks need to be, so that if the page changes size based on viewport or orientation, the text will reflow and repage accordingly. The algorithm presented at your link does no such thing.

Comment: @JaSuperior, Did you read and understand the linked page correctly?  It has the script and examples to guide you to the algorithm.  In fact, it actually does give you the right place assuming a page length of 960px and 100px. You should read all the answers and try out the fiddles attached therein. This forum is to guide you, not to do your job.

Comment: For whoever that down-voted this answer, should have courtesy to provide the reason. Down-votes without a reason is lame.

Comment: I downvoted. And I told you why. Although you believe it to be the correct answer, I can't see what your link has to do with anything. I've tried the fiddles, and read their answers. And although, their print implementation seems to describe something similar to what we're looking for, the algorithm presented does no such thing.  So i downvoted.