# Rich content overflow in new element

Tags: html, css, angular, overflow, epub

I looking for a way to achieve that in Ionic 4 (Angular 8)

[image]

When the content overflow the fixed height (i.e height of the screen) the content is push to a new block (a new "page") and you can swipe accross "pages".
The same way ebook/epub readers work (with variable font-size, line-height, etc). I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52194914/2765126) but I don't see how I could make it works with angular `<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>`.